# Word ordering for sequels of works whose titles start with 'The'

Tags: word-order, titles, sort-ordering

Hopefully a simple one, but my Google-fu is letting me down.

Typically, when alpabetising titles, I would move the 'The' to the end of the title but, in the case of a sequel, should that be moved to before or after a sequel numeral?

For example:

- Amazing Spider-Man, The
- Amazing Spider-Man, The 2
- Amazing Spider-Man 2, The

Which of the latter two is traditionally correct?

Comment: sure, it's the last one

Comment: _Prequels_ would lead to a tangled web.

Comment: What are you alphabetising and why? This will make a big difference to how you do it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - how so?

Comment: @Araucaria - in this case, I was renaming some movie filenames, so they would sort better on my home media server, but it could apply to books too.

Comment: Amazing Spider-Man -1, The

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - touche; it's hard enough with the awful colon subtitles!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last version listed is correct: "Amazing Spider-Man 2, The" adding the 2 at the end is confusing and non-intuitive while omitting it entirely does not resolve conflicts between sequels. Additionally, adding the number before the comma still keeps sequels ordered intuitively and is also easier to read. The only reason people move 'the' to the end of ordered list titles is to prevent a huge, useless cluster of elements under 'T' that people would be more likely to look for under other letters. This is not a concern with a number that comes at the end of a title and thus the number does not have to be moved.